# How to define click event on click and href event when user opens a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is very specific requirement but was wondering if this is possible.

I have a header menu, "Create Report". I had defined "click" event for this. On clicking this menu, it opens a new modal, without changing the route.. and once user feeds some data there and clicks submit, it changes the route to "/reports" and shows the data.

But problem with this approach is, when user want to open this link (header menu Create report) in new tab (right click and open in new tab), it doesn't open anything.. may be new tab could not understand this.

One solution is to replace click with href, so instead I can do, href="/report". But this way, as soon as user clicks this link, it changes the route, to "/report", which I do not want. I want to change the route when user submits the report.

I can not use ng-click/ ng-href due to some techinal limitation with my current project.

I hope my question is clear, please let me know if you know of a solution or you want any more information.

Comment: please specify if the new tab is opened by right clicking on the submit button in modal?

Comment: "when user want to open this link"  .. which link?

Comment: @CharlieH I updated my question.. I mean "Create Report" from Header menu.

Comment: Ok."Opens a new modal" What does this mean? What is the angular version do you use?

Comment: This mean, it opens a aside modal.. ( a form to fill some data). I use angular 1.7

Answer (score 0):

While submitting the report from modal, send user submitted data via ajax and save data in session as well. Then create report from that data.
Once data is in session, you can create reports in new tab as well.

Comment: Sorry.. my question was unclear to you.. I just want to open the modal.. when user click the Report link from the header menu without changing the route. ( in same tab or using mouse, open link in other tab). In same tab, its working fine.. but in new tab.. it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if understand You correctly but You can achieve this effect by replacing in modal window your submit button with link and nested button. Like this:

```
<a href="/report" target="_parent">
    <button onclick="form.submit()">Submit</button>
</a>
```